# Canvas element in Webview being drawn only some of the time

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, webview

I'm using a Webview in my android app. I'm placing a 2d canvas over a webgl canvas (webgl commented out here). Now, when I start up the app, half the time it draws the expected path, and half the time it draws nothing. Am I missing something? Could this be a caching problem or something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Cardboard container</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*background-color: black;*/
  }
  #container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
  }
  #stamp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 160px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
  }
  #bezier{
    z-index: 2;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="stamp"></div>
<canvas id="bezier">Error creating bezier canvas</canvas>

<script src="js/third-party/threejs/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/third-party/threejs/StereoEffect.js"></script>
<script src="js/webgl.js"></script>
<script src="js/bezier.js"></script>

<script>

var consecutiveAbsentFrames = 6;
var totalFrames = 90;
var frameCount = 0;
var straightLineSpeed = 0.05;
var scaleFactor = 0.9;

var numGridPoints = 196; 
var fovRadius = 9;
var fovXoffset = 0.5;
var gridPoints = []; // Points are an array [x0,y0,x1,y1,...]
var gridPoints2d = [];
var completePath = []; 
var pathIndex = 0;

init();

function init() {

  stamp = document.getElementById('stamp');

  init2d();
}


function init2d(){
  var b = document.getElementById('bezier');
  b.width = window.innerWidth * scaleFactor * 0.5;
  b.height = window.innerHeight;
  var ctx=b.getContext('2d');

  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(100,100);
  ctx.stroke();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** 
Behavior is normal on a Moto X with Android 5.1, incorrect on Note 5 with 5.1.1

Comment: what is `resize` can we see that code too

Comment: I think if you increase the timeout value from `1` to `1000` you'll see what's happening is that the canvase is being drawn but immediately erased due to resize being called immediately after

Comment: Sorry, I have in fact removed the resize listener. The problem persists. I'll edit my code.

Comment: are you using something like cordova? or just trying to access the javascript files using relative paths?

Comment: can you check if there is a problem loading the page? I see all the JS and HTML to be fine assuming that the <script> tag ends at the end which may be a typo. If not please add that </script at the end

Comment: No cordova, just using relative paths. Closing tags are there, console returns no errors.

Comment: Also, it seems to work fine on my Moto X. This strange behavior is occurring on a Note 5.